# How do I pass response values from extension to custom response type in IBM Watson Assistant chat?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

The below JSON defines custom response for the client to allow custom UI. As per the documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-response-types-reference#user_defined I can define "anything" for the "user_defined" object but I am failing to understand how to pass the variable as provided by my extension response.

```json
{
  "generic": [
    {
      "user_defined": {
        "default_color": "blue",
        "template_name": "color_picker",
        "my_response_value": "???"
      },
      "response_type": "user_defined"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to this response type in the (new) Watson Assistant? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-response-types-reference#user_defined

Comment: @data_henrik yup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some trial and error it seems that it works with the expression lang as described here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-call-extension#extension-check-status

For example

```json
{
  "generic": [
    {
      "user_defined": {
        "default_color": "blue",
        "template_name": "color_picker",
        "my_second_value": "${step_170_result_1.body.base_code}"
      },
      "response_type": "user_defined"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the property "my_second_value" will be replaced by the value from the "session variables/extension response". Your reference will differ in the `step` value and `result` value.